# Написать функцию на PHP

Tags: php

Создать 3 переменные. Две из них должны содержать число. Третья - знак арифметической операции. Создать одну функцию, которая будет подсчитывать первые две переменные, в зависимости от третьей переменной.

Как можно реализовать это внутри одной php функции без if(switch)?

Так как я новичок, не могу сделать.

Вот мой код, но не получается:

```php
<?php

   $num1 = 58;
   $num2 = 42;
   $op = '+';


    function calc ($num1 , $num2, $op)
    {
        printf("$num1.$op.$num2=%d",$num1,$op,$num2);
    }

    calc($num1,$num2,$op);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

   $num1 = 58;
   $num2 = 42;
   $op = '+';


    function calc ($num1 , $num2, $op)
    {
        eval('echo '.$num1.$op.$num2.';');
    }

    calc($num1,$num2,$op);
?>
```